# Parsing json in jQuery with 'load more option'

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have valid data in jquery, how to I loop every item I get back and display it in html container div. Thanks

ie.

item 1 
  image 123
Item 2
 Image 123

```
{"ERRORS":[],"DATA":[{"itemValidFrom":"October, 25 2011 00:00:00","itemActive":true,"itemTxt":"test","itemID":"30d2f2c1-58ca-4b3d-b3e0-d284ae5b25ab","itemValidTo":"October, 19 2011 00:00:00","itemName":"test","itemModified":"October, 05 2011 00:00:00","itemCreated":"October, 03 2011 00:00:00","image":{"imageCreated":"October, 05 2011 00:00:00","imageURL":"firefox-girl.jpg","imageID":"bc869a94-fee5-4fc8-bd21-e2de2f020310"}],"MESSAGES":[{"CURRENTPAGE":1.0,"TOTALPAGES":1.0}]}

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'api/default.php/id/0f4addd8',
    data: 'apiKeytest=182j&?perPage=2&currentPage=1',
    dataType: "json",
    context: document.body,
    success: function(r) {
    jQuery('#posts-container').replaceWith(r);
            console.log(r);
                        }

    });

    });

</script>


<!-- Widget HTML Starts Here -->
<div id="posts-container">
    <!-- Posts go inside this DIV -->
    <div id="posts"></div>
    <!-- Load More "Link" -->
    <div id="load-more">Load More</div>
</div>
<!-- Widget HTML Ends Here -->
```

Comment: Can you elaborate. Valid data in jquery does not make much sense.

Comment: Sorry I mean in FF console by making that call I get the example Json data posted above. What I want to do is loop everything in "DATA" of the json and display it on the page. The example json only shows one item in DATA but there could be more. I then want to get the item in "MESSAGES" (only ever 1 item in there [1]) and use it so I know how may pages there are and the page I am on (maybe to make a second call later). I just don't know in jquery how to list the data on a page. i.e. I have the json back now how to I display each item in "DATA" part of the result on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the json data with a `for` loop and build your custom output to append to the DOM:

```
success: function(r) {
    var output = '';
    for (a in r.DATA) {
        for (b in r.DATA[a]) {
            if (typeof(r.DATA[a][b]) == 'object') {
                for (c in r.DATA[a][b]) {
                    output += c + ' = ' + r.DATA[a][b][c] + '<br />';
                }
            } else {
                output += b + ' = ' + r.DATA[a][b] + '<br />';
            }
        }
    }
    jQuery('#posts-container').append(output);
}
```

`a` corresponds to each key in the object returned by your ajax call.

I created a jsfiddle of the above code and noticed that there is an error in the json output you posted in your question; a closing bracket (`}`) was omitted from the end of the `DATA` array (which has only one key, `0`).

Here is the link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EpjyH/1/

Comment: that's really cool and helps me a lot, i now get the results however i also get a lot of other code appended to the result after which i cannot see where it is coming from i.e. argumentNames = function () { var names = this.toString().match(/^[\s\(]*function[^(]*\((.*?)\)/)[1].split(",").invoke("strip"); return names.length == 1 && !names[0] ? [] : names; }